# Multiplying 2 Alias Together in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, alias, multiplication

I have an assignment to make a SELECT STATEMENT using no FROM clause.
I'm trying to multiply the Price and TaxRate to make a TaxAmount column but I'm getting an error saying invalid column name for Price and TaxRate.

```
SELECT '100 (dollars)' AS Price, '.07 (7 percent)' AS TaxRate,
Price * TaxRate AS TaxAmount, TaxAmount + Price AS Total
```

Comment: You can't use an alias in the select statement. Even if you could, what is `100 (dollars)` * `.07 (7 percent)` supposed to equal? You can't multiply strings. `SELECT '100 (dollars)' AS Price, '.07 (7 percent)' AS TaxRate,
100 * .07 AS TaxAmount, 100 * 1.07 AS Total` should work though

Comment: Is there any way to convert the 100 and the .07 and make them as an integar? I'm supposed to make Price column to look like 100 (dollars)

Comment: `.07` is not an integer. What is your actual assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT 100 AS Price, .07 AS TaxRate, (100 * .07) AS TaxAmount, ((100 * .07) + 100) AS Total`

You don't need to make it look like 100 (dollars) I don't think, that wouldn't make sense. If you actually do, you could use

`SELECT '100 (dollars)' AS Price, '.07 (7 percent)' AS TaxRate, (100 * .07) AS TaxAmount, ((100 * .07) + 100) AS Total`

Comment: Ok thanks! That's what I was thinking to do. But I'm over thinking myself. :)